# Retrieve a Java.Util.List from a Flux in Spring Web Reactive Framework

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have an endpoint that should get an excel document using an ExcelUtility class that expects a Java.Util.List.

I am using Mongodb to fetch data, but Mongodb returns a Flux myList.

How can I "give" the ExcelUtility class the List myList to generate a Workbook class that I can return in the ResponseEntity?

So far I have this code:

```
final Workbook myWorkBook = ExcelUtils                               
.pojo2xlsx(this.myMongoRepository.findAll()
.toStream().collect(Collectors.toList()), 
 MyType.class);
```

The method myMongoRepository.findAll returns a Flux < MyType >. It's a standard ReactiveMongoRepository interface.

I guess the problem boils down to that I need to "block" the stream to get the list so my custom Excel service can take a regular list. I can do that in test code, but when running in the Web Reactive Framework, it seems to be not allowed to block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are calling this from a reactive context you want

```
Mono<Workbook> wb = s.collectList().map(l -> ExcelUtils.pojo2xlsx(l));
```

In this scenario you don't want to start the work yourself or cause blocking within the threads managed by the reactive scheduler. You would simply return this new Mono to the framework and let it decide when and how to schedule the work.

However if you are calling this from a normal method that needs to return the workbook, then you have no choice but to block, but the expectation of this synchronous method is that you will start the work and block until it is complete anyway.

Comment: Thanks, almost there it seems. How do I convert the Mono < Workbook> wb to a 'Mono<ResponseEntity <?>>' This is supposed to be a webservice call.

Comment: @ArmandoPerea `map` can be used to transfrom a synchronous `Mono`. `Mono<ResponseEntity<Workbook>> wb = s.collectList().map(l -> new ResponseEntity<Workbook>(ExcelUtils.pojo2xlsx(l), HttpStatus.OK));`